# spans adding up to parent in bootstrap not working if in well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="well well-large">
            <h3>Place an Order</h3>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">Bid Price</div>
                <div class="span2">Execute</div>
                <div class="span3">Ask Price</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

That's my structure. The Bid Price, Execute and Ask Price should all fit on the same row. Because they're in a well, they appear not to. Is this known behavior and is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Why does the nested row not fit in one line?

The problem is the padding and the border from the `well` element. `span8` class has a fixed width of  620px when is inside a normal `row`.

[image: First situation]

The `well-large` element has a padding of 24px (green part) and a border of 1px, so the nested row will be inside the blue part. But the blue part doesn't have a 620px width, it has a 570px width.

[image: Width inside the well element]

The `span` elements inside the nested row has also a fixed width. `span2` has a width of 140px and `span3` has a width of 220px.

[image: Width of the spans]

If you add all the widths from the `span` elements and their margins (220px + 140px + 220px + (20px * 2) = 620px), the total width of the row is greater than the `well` element (570px), so the last element is being pushed to the next line.

## How to solve it?

**First attempt**

My first and easier solution, is to put the class `span8` in the `well` element like that ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndt7e/)):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span8 well well-large">
      <h3>Place an Order</h3>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="span3">Bid Price</div>
         <div class="span2">Execute</div>
         <div class="span3">Ask Price</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This solves the previous problem, but add one problem. Since the padding is now in the `span8` element, the main grid is broken, since the well element has a width of 670px (to the width of 620px, you have to add 50px from padding and border of the well).

[image: Second situation]

But now the blue part, has 620px of width, so all the elements of the nested row can fit perfectly in the blue part. But as I said before, the grid is broken. For example, if you add a `span4` element after the `span8`, the `span4` is being pushed to the next line, like was happening before with the nested elements.

So with this layout ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LpML/)):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 well well-large">
         <!-- Some ramdom text -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
         <!-- Some ramdom text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You have this result:

[image: Problem with first solution]

**Final solution**

If you want 3 columns inside a `well`, you need to different grid system. One solution can be using `row-fluid` instead of `row`. With `row-fluid`, the width of the `span` elements is a percentage, instead of a fixed width.

With this layout ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Btn7c/)):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="well well-large">
            <h3>Place an Order</h3>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">Bid Price</div>
                <div class="span4">Execute</div>
                <div class="span4">Ask Price</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can achieve something similar to what you wanted really. If you want a exact proportion of 3/8, 2/8 and 3/8 (like your initial setup with spans), you have to use CSS to make a three column layout, you can't do it using only bootstrap `span` elements.

Comment: I thought that you shouldn't put `span` and `well` classes on the same element?

Comment: @Shannon Yes, my solution is not perfect and has some side effects since I break the grid putting the `span8` class inside the well. I edited my question with a new JSFiddle (the last was wrong). I can't now, because I am going to work, but when I come back nobody answered this, I will extend my answer.

Comment: @Shamoon I edited the question with more information and another possible solution, I hope it helps :).